# how to display html within a javascript variable option

Tags: javascript, html

hello i am working with a slot machine game built in html5, the idea is when ever u get win or lose a message is displayed, using this

```
var BLURB_TBL = [
'No win!',];
```

but now i wnt the text displayed to be a link, where by after it is shown it can also be clicked, i have tried this but it kips displaying the raw html code

```
var BLURB_TBL = [
'<a href="#">No win!</a>',];
```

please what can i do so that the html am trying to out put comes properly

Comment: What are you doing with the variable after you assign a value to it?

Comment: How are you adding it to the DOM? Why is it an array by the way?

Comment: Show us how you show that message. Where `BLURB_TBL` is used?

Comment: ok, first of all i display it as a message

Comment: @stackstack what kind of message? In `alert` box? In HTML or where? Show us how do you display it.

Comment: its in an array because there are different messages to be shown, thats just an example i used

Comment: @stackstack - you haven't really answered the question, how are you displaying it as a message? How are you adding it to the DOM? jQuery `append`? `innerHTML`?

Comment: it is supposed to be displayed in this  <span id="multiplier">0</span> x <img src="img/gold-64.png"/>

Comment: OK... *how* are you putting it in there?  Show us the code!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with

```
var BLURB_TBL = ['<a href="#">No win!</a>',];
```

What happens next matters. For example, if this is displayed with javascript like this:

```
document.getElementByID("containerid").innerText = BLURB_TBL[0];
```

it should be changed to

```
document.getElementByID("containerid").innerHTML = BLURB_TBL[0];
```

Or if the message is displayed with jQuery like this:

```
$(containerselector).text(BLURB_TBL[0]);
// or
jQuery(containerselector).text(BLURB_TBL[0]);
```

it should be changed to

```
$(containerselector).html(BLURB_TBL[0]);
// or
jQuery(containerselector).html(BLURB_TBL[0]);
```

So, what happens with your message after it is assigned to BLURB_TBL? Where and how is it used?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but my guess is that your answer makes an assumption not supported by the question as it stands now and at the time of your answer.  Or, it could be because your code will throw JavaScript errors because of an incorrect function name.  Maybe the twain.